# Trying to Use Gulp to Run Sass

Tags: django, sass, gulp

I'm trying to set up Gulp to watch and compile my sass file in my Django project

I followed the app doc to install gulp. The sample task worked. Every answer I saw to run sass was different. This version runs but it doesn't handle a scss change:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

function defaultTask(cb) {
  gulp.watch('base/static/base/css/stylesheets/main.scss', sassCompile);
   cb();
 }
exports.default = defaultTask

function sassCompile(cb) {
  return gulp.src('base/static/base/css/stylesheets/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
    .pipe(gulp.dest('base/static/base/css/main.css'));
  cb();
}
exports.sass = sassCompile;

// function watch() {
//   gulp.watch('base/static/base/css/stylesheets/main.scss', sassCompile);
// }
// exports.watch = watch; // don't forget to export your command!
```

The output from running gulp is:

```
[22:17:09] Using gulpfile ~/htdocs/myproject/gulpfile.js
[22:17:09] Starting 'default'...
[22:17:09] Finished 'default' after 3.29 ms
```

I have to ctrl-C to stop it.

gulp version 4.0.2 on MacOS.

This is how I manually run sass:

> /usr/local/bin/sass base/static/base/css/stylesheets/main.scss: base/static/base/css/main.css

### Fixed

Based on @Mark's comments this is the working version:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

function defaultTask() {
  gulp.watch('base/static/base/css/stylesheets/**/*.scss', sassCompile);
 }
exports.default = defaultTask

function sassCompile() {
  return gulp.src('base/static/base/css/stylesheets/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
    .pipe(gulp.dest('base/static/base/css'));
}
exports.sass = sassCompile;
```

Comment: Well, you don't show a `sass` task.  You do have a `watch` and a `default` task.  You need a `sass` task where you `gulp.src` to a `pipe(sass())`.  Lots of recent examples online.  Look at the `gulp-sass` documentation.  (And I wouldn't call both my task `sass` and the plugin `sass` as you have it.  It'll be confusing sooner or later.)

Comment: @Mark. I tried another example

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code now except `gulp.dest()` takes a directory name.  Sass will create the `main.css` file automatically.  The `cb and cb()` in `sassCompile` are  unnecessary and will never be reached anyhow due to the `return` statement - which is enough on its own.  Itested your code with these changes and it works fine.

Comment: "I have to ctrl-C to stop it."  This is normal - it is watching for file changes until you kill the task.

Comment: @Mark, that fixed it. If you enter that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You originally had no `sass` task defined, something like:

```
function sass2css() {
  return gulp.src('relative path (from the gulpfile.js file) to your main.scss')
    .pipe(sass()) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('must be a directory name here'));
}
```

is the general form.  In your edited question you added a `sass` task that used a filename (`....main.css`)  in the `gulp.dest()` call.  I pointed out that should be a directory name and that `main.css` is automatically created by `gulp-sass` so there is no need to name it yourself.  Otherwise, I tested your code and it was working.

You also had both a `cb` (callback function) and a `return` statement in your `sassCompile` task.  The `cb()` call would never be reached because of the `return` statement and the `return` statement is sufficient in this case to signal async completion to `gulp` so you could remove all references to `cb` in this task.